# Returning the position (Rank) in an array

Tags: php, arrays, ranking

I have an array:

```
$age_array = array("Tom" => "20", "Sandra" => "17", "Kevin" => "35");
```

I sort first the array from old to young and then I want to return the position of Sandra (The rank). Something like:

Sandra - 17 years old - **Rank 3**

or

Kevin- 35 years old - **Rank 1**

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

I got it to work with this code using `array_keys()` combined with `array_search`:

```
$age_array = array("Tom" => "20", "Sandra" => "17", "Kevin" => "35");
arsort($age_array);
echo array_search("Kevin",array_keys($age_array))+1;
```

Comment: Take a look at: `print_r(array_keys($age_array));` and then combine it with `array_search()`; If you get stuck, show what you came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_keys($age_array)` will return an array of the keys from which you can get the rank. See the documentation and some samples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Comment: OP also has to use `array_search()` to get to his goal.